# Define and edit Custom tag values for linked attribute(source/target end of association) in Enterprise-architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a requirement to generate custom Java code based on association between two classes , I have created a profile containing custom stereotyped association and stereotyped association role with my tag values defined .
when I import the profile and create association between classes using custom stereotype and change the stereotype of association  role to my defined stereotype association role I don't have an option to edit association role tag values , which I want to use in my linked attribute template to generate code . how do I add linked attribute tag values from UI ?

Comment: To get best-value from this forum you are better off trying something that gets you somewhere toward your goal. if that doesn't work post an example of what you see instead of what you expected. As it stands you are asking either for opinions or a tutorial. There are better places to gather either of these.

Comment: Where do you expect tagged values for the roles? There are none.

Answer (score 1):

Custom tagged values are only added automatically if the element / connector is created with the proper stereotype. They do not get added or removed when a stereotype is set on an already-created element / connector.

You are first creating a regular association and then changing the stereotype, so the tagged values do not appear.

What you need to do is to "synchronize" the stereotype. The simple way if you're working with an imported profile is to open the resources window, find the stereotype under "UML Profiles", right-click it and select "Synchronize Tagged Values and Constraints".

The preferred way of working is to create a custom diagram type and toolbox as well as the profile. This allows you to draw your stereotyped associations directly instead of setting the stereotype manually and synchronizing afterwards. Drawing the connector from a custom toolbox will set the tagged values.

A custom toolbox also allows you to add the tagged values to existing elements / connectors with your stereotype, again by right-clicking it in the toolbox and selecting "synchronize stereotype."

Adding a custom diagram and toolbox means you need to create an MDG Technology rather than just a profile.

As an alternative, you can add a quick linker definition file to your profile. This will also allow you to create new stereotyped connectors with the tagged values, but it won't help with connectors you've already created.

Comment: I think you can also do `Synchronize stereotype` from the stereotype in the Resources view if you don't have a toolbox from an MDG.

Comment: That's absolutely right, and simpler than creating an MDG Technology. I've modified the answer accordingly.